# How do you import your Java Project to a repository?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am facing an issue that involves Github, Git and java code.

My goal is to clone an existing repository on Github to my computer and add my java project to the repo.

What I did first was grabbing the SSH key and cloning it to my machine, all good and fine, and then, next thing I did was using cp or copy and copied my java class into the repository.

The problem here is that this is simply a copy that never becomes updated. The original java class gets updated in a whole other directory called "IdeaProjects" (I am using IntelliJ).

So how can I properly add my java project to the repository so it keeps updating for every change I make in the code, in the editor?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

---

In IntelliJ:

- Checkout from Version Control - for clone from GitHub

Or for existing project:

- Create Git repositiry..  - create a local repository
- Share project on GitHub - share project on GitHub to new or existing
  repo (which are connected in the Settings - Vertion Control - GitHub)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and hassel free way:
1. Download and install desktop github client: https://desktop.github.com/

2.Create a repo/Clone a repo. Go to File->Clone repo(If your repo is created already)/Create a repo(In case of new repo)

3.Commit and Push. Your repo should be created and pushed with a blank folder

4.After cloning and creating your repo,you will move all your java files at that directory

5.Now whenever you want to commit somnething, use commit from github client and push it to github.

For any confusion,ask me again.I will be happy to help